# Create Bar-line graph using Report Viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, charts, reporting, report-viewer2010

I wanted to create a Bar-line graph using report viewer in MVC4 c#,couldn't fine any thing useful about it in internet. 
If it a achievable task or is there any other methods to achieve this task.

Please share your thoughts,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a way to do it in report viewer MVC4,which served by purpose. While creating the graph in report viewer and assigning the values to the data field area of the graph. You can change the graph type by **right-click on the field -> choosing the change chart type and selecting the desired type**.
By this way any combination of graphs could be created.